# Initial ghost text cleared and font color changed to black on user input

Tags: jquery, css

I have some textboxes on my page with ghost text that clears on focus. I figured how to change the font to black on user input, but I can't figure out how set the font color back to silver if the user clears the textbox of input.

Any help would be appreciated

Jquery in header:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').focus(function () {
        $(this).val('');
        if ((this).val !== '') {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:18px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Sample textbox markup:

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="txtLastName"
    runat="server"
    MaxLength="50"
    onblur="if(this.value == ''){ (this.value = 'Last Name';) (this.css ('color', 'silver');)}"
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'Last Name'){this.value = '';}"
    Text="Last Name">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting all of your jQuery onBlur and onFocus into the jQuery section of your code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val == '') {
            $(this).val = "Last Name";
            $(this).css('color', 'silver');
        }
    });
    $('input:text').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val == 'Last Name') {
            $(this).val = "";
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new HTML5 placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the placeholder attribute instead of all this, Visual Studio will probably squiggly line it as an error but it still works fine in most browsers (unless You're using VS2012 then it recognizes it.

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="txtLastName"
    Placeholder = "Last Name"
    runat="server"
    MaxLength="50"
    onblur="if(this.value == ''){ (this.value = 'Last Name';) (this.css ('color', 'silver');)}"
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'Last Name'){this.value = '';}"
    Text="Last Name">
</asp:TextBox>
```

When the user deletes all the text in the box the placeholder returns. Just don't use this in place of a label, it's not screenreader friendly (neither is the way you're doing it btw)